# nginx rewrite to alphabetized subdirectory

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, directory

I'm trying to convert the following Apache mod_rewrite rule into an appropriate nginx format:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)/([^\/])([^\/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %1/%2/%2%3 -d
RewriteRule ^/?.* /%2/%2%3 [L]
```

In practice, this rule rewrites bare directory requests to place them within a parent directory based upon the first character (case-sensitive), so `http://example.com/foobar` becomes `http://example.com/f/foobar` and so on.

Everything else is either static content, or PHP and passed on with FastCGI, and there are `location`handlers in place for them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll lose the directory test in your second `RewriteCond`, but:

```
rewrite ^/([^/])([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1$2 last;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    location ~ /([^/])([^/]+)/?$ {
        set $firstletter $1;
        set $sub $2;
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^ /$firstletter/$firstletter$sub last;
        }
    }
```